# import React Components to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to generalize my code by keeping a .js file containing only React components in one file and then utilizing these components in an HTML file. Here is my simple component:

**component.js**

```
'use strict'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MyComponent">
          <p>Text goes here.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If in my `component.js` file I add: `ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.querySelector('#div-1'));` and then, in my HTML, add `<script src="component.js" type="text/jsx"></script>` the React component shows in my page as expected.

However, my end goal is to be able to add the `ReactDOM.render` into my HTML within a script tag, that way I can have multiple pages utilizing the `component.js` components while doing all the assigning in the HTML page. Something like:

**mypage.html** (simplified)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="component.js" type="text/jsx"></script>  //import my components (no assigning done in this file)
  <div id="div-1"><div>
  <script>
    ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.querySelector('#div-1'));   //assign to div
  </script>
</html>
```

However this above code fails, with many errors regarding `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

With that, how would I go about carrying something like this out? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that JSX isn't recognized by default in a browser.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` that's what this error means.

React docs have following help regarding that: [quickly try JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx)

you need to add babel in script tags and add `type="text/babel"` in whichever script you're using JSX.

```html
    <div id="counter_container"></div>
    <!-- add babel support -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="components.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      (() => {
        const Counter = window.Counter;
        const counterContainerEl = document.querySelector('#counter_container');
        ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, counterContainerEl);
      })();//this is just to avoid polluting global scope
    </script>
```

I've put together a short example here [github-repo](https://github.com/lawki/react-in-html)